# Python remove special characters in file

Tags: python

I have a file with following format:

```
[" '                      'battery status OK "]
["                        'memory status OK "]
["                        'power_supplies redundancy Redundant", " 'power_supplies Battery 1 capacity 96 Watts"]
["                        'processor status OK "]
["                        'storage status OK "]
```

Could some body help to remove or strim those special charracter to new file has only text ?

Thanks

Comment: What is your desired o/p, also have you tried anything ?

Comment: Do you mean just A-Z and a-z characters and nothing else?

Comment: sometimes when the input is bogus, best way is to smack the person who created this with a bat until he/she changes it (you can rent Chuck Norris if you don't want to get your hands dirty)

Comment: What 'special' characters do you want to remove?

Comment: Thanks Owain Esau, that's what i need